# Oracle SQL - Most Recent List of Records with a Max and Min Amount

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports-2008

Hello I have what I hope is an interesting problem (well a couple problems to be precise) and I am hoping someone can help me.  I am currently working in SQL in Crystal Reports 2008 which is getting its data from an Oracle database.

I need to obtain a list of staff who have done a certain minimum number of tests, say over 10 tests, in a given time period. To further cloud the issue it must be the most recent 10 tests and I also need a list of each unique test references.

I have made a start (see first piece of code and its output) which uses the ROW NUMBER() function but this only shows the 10 most recent pieces of information for a single staff number and does not check if the required 10 tests have been conducted.

I have also produced another piece of code (see second piece of code and its output) that incorporates a count function to and only shows those staff who have conducted at least 10 tests.

What I really need is shown in the Required Output table:

So my questions/problems are:

1. Is there a way to modify my original code so that it will work with more than one staff number?
2. Is there a way to merge both pieces of code so that it checks if the required number of tests has been completed and only displays those staff numbers and test references that meet the required criteria (this is the preferred option)?
3. Do I have to scrap this and idea and start again?

Unfortunately I currently do not have administrator access to the databases and cannot create any new data tables to store any of this data so I need this to be done in a single SQL action, if possible.

I have attached a spreadsheet which shows a snapshot of the data available if this helps.

Any help you can give me, it would be appreciated.

```
WITH TESTNUMBER AS
(SELECT TESTER.STAFF_NO, TESTER.TEST_REF, PERIOD. DATE_OF_TEST, TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME,
ROW NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TESTER.STAFF_NO DESC, PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST DESC, 
TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME DESC)
AS RowNumber            
FROM dB1.TEST_EVENT TESTER      
INNER JOIN dB1.PERIOD PERIOD ON TESTER.PERIOD_ID=PERIOD.PERIOD_ID
INNER JOIN dB1.TEST_ SLOT_TIME TESTSLOT ON TESTER.SLOT_TIME_ID=TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME_ID)
WHERE TESTER.STAFF_NO=405405 AND    
(PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST>={ts '2013-08-01 00:00:00'} AND
PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST<={ts '2013-08-10 00:00:00'})

SELECT * FROM TESTNUMBER        
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10;`

STAFF_NO    TEST_REF    DATE_OF_TEST    SLOT_TIME    
405405  01  05/08/2013  08:40:00
405405  02  05/08/2013  09:40:00
405405  03  05/08/2013  10:40:00
405405  04  06/08/2013  08:40:00
405405  05  06/08/2013  09:40:00
405405  06  06/08/2013  10:40:00
405405  07  06/08/2013  11:40:00
405405  08  07/08/2013  08:40:00
405405  09  07/08/2013  09:40:00
405405  10  07/08/2013  10:40:00
```

The query:

```
SELECT TESTER.STAFF_NO, count(TESTER.STAFF_NO) AS TOTALTESTS FROM 
FROM dB1.TEST_EVENT TESTER      
INNER JOIN dB1.PERIOD PERIOD ON TESTER.PERIOD_ID=PERIOD.PERIOD_ID
INNER JOIN dB1.TEST_ SLOT_TIME TESTSLOT ON TESTER.SLOT_TIME_ID=TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME_ID)
WHERE (PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST>={ts '2013-08-01 00:00:00'} AND PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST<=
{ts '2013-08-10 00:00:00'})
GROUP BY TESTER.STAFF_NO        
HAVING count(TESTER.STAFF_NO)>=10   
ORDER BY TESTER.STAFF_NO DESC`  

STAFF_NO    TEST_REF        
405405  12          
366255  14
```

Overall Required Output

```
STAFF_NO    TEST_REF    DATE_OF_TEST    SLOT_TIME    
405405  03  05/08/2013  10:40:00    
405405  04  06/08/2013  08:40:00   
405405  05  06/08/2013  09:40:00    
405405  06  06/08/2013  10:40:00
405405  07  06/08/2013  11:40:00
405405  08  07/08/2013  08:40:00
405405  09  07/08/2013  09:40:00
405405  10  07/08/2013  10:40:00
405405  11  08/08/2013  08:40:00
405405  12  08/08/2013  09:40:00
366255  17  06/08/2013  09:40:00
366255  18  06/08/2013  10:40:00
366255  19  06/08/2013  11:40:00
366255  20  06/08/2013  12:40:00
366255  21  09/08/2013  08:40:00
366255  22  09/08/2013  09:40:00
366255  23  09/08/2013  10:40:00
366255  24  09/08/2013  12:40:00
366255  25  09/08/2013  14:40:00
366255  26  09/08/2013  15:40:00
```

Sorry if this doesn't look very professional but I am new to this.

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Nothing but *merged* version of both your queries.

For **Question #1**

```
WITH TESTNUMBER AS
(SELECT TESTER.STAFF_NO, TESTER.TEST_REF, PERIOD. DATE_OF_TEST, TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME,
ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TESTER.STAFF_NO ORDER BY TESTER.STAFF_NO DESC, PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST DESC, 
TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME DESC)
AS RowNumber            
FROM dB1.TEST_EVENT TESTER      
INNER JOIN dB1.PERIOD PERIOD ON TESTER.PERIOD_ID=PERIOD.PERIOD_ID
INNER JOIN dB1.TEST_ SLOT_TIME TESTSLOT ON TESTER.SLOT_TIME_ID=TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME_ID)
WHERE TESTER.STAFF_NO in (405405, 366255) AND    
(PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST>={ts '2013-08-01 00:00:00'} AND
PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST<={ts '2013-08-10 00:00:00'})
SELECT * FROM TESTNUMBER        
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY STAFF_NO,RowNumber
```

**Question #2**

```
WITH TESTNUMBER AS
(
SELECT TESTER.STAFF_NO, TESTER.TEST_REF, PERIOD. DATE_OF_TEST, TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME,
ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TESTER.STAFF_NO ORDER BY TESTER.STAFF_NO DESC, PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST DESC, 
TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME DESC)
AS RowNumber            
FROM dB1.TEST_EVENT TESTER      
INNER JOIN dB1.PERIOD PERIOD ON TESTER.PERIOD_ID=PERIOD.PERIOD_ID
INNER JOIN dB1.TEST_ SLOT_TIME TESTSLOT ON TESTER.SLOT_TIME_ID=TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME_ID)
WHERE TESTER.STAFF_NO in (
                          SELECT TESTER.STAFF_NO FROM 
                          FROM dB1.TEST_EVENT TESTER      
                          INNER JOIN dB1.PERIOD PERIOD
                              ON TESTER.PERIOD_ID = PERIOD.PERIOD_ID
                          INNER JOIN dB1.TEST_ SLOT_TIME TESTSLOT 
                              ON TESTER.SLOT_TIME_ID = TESTSLOT.SLOT_TIME_ID)
                          WHERE (PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST >= {ts '2013-08-01 00:00:00'} 
                           AND PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST <= {ts '2013-08-10 00:00:00'})
                          GROUP BY TESTER.STAFF_NO        
                          HAVING count(TESTER.STAFF_NO)>=10
                          )
AND (PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST>={ts '2013-08-01 00:00:00'} 
AND PERIOD.DATE_OF_TEST<={ts '2013-08-10 00:00:00'}
)
SELECT * FROM TESTNUMBER        
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY STAFF_NO,RowNumber
```

Comment: Hello again, I tried to post my response via this comment and was told it was too long, I will thereforre use the "Answer Your Question" instead.